# Vlookup combined with first following date in list

Tags: excel, date, lookup

I have two separate tables each consisting of a "container number" column, and "date" field.

In sheet 1 I want to create an excel formula in a new column 3 to look up a date in sheet 2. This date should be the date first found but subsequent or equal to "sheet1/columnB date" for a given container number.

For example:
Sheet 1

```
MMAU1109032 15/2/2015  ..16/1/2015  
MMAU1109032 20/2/2015  ..20/2/2015  
MMAU1109285 27/11/2015 ..29/11/2015
```

Sheet 2:

```
MMAU1108695 30/11/2015  
MMAU1108859 26/3/2015  
MMAU1109032 16/1/2015  
MMAU1109032 20/2/2015  
MMAU1109285 29/11/2015  
MMAU1110033 30/12/2014  
MMAU1110054 30/9/2015  
MMAU1110687 26/1/2015
```

An idea anyone?

Comment: First line on sheet one:  15/2/2015 is after 16/1/2015.  I believe there is a typo.

Comment: you are right about the typo - your first function proposal nails it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2010 or later then use this regular formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$8/((Sheet2!$A$1:$A$8=A1)*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$8>=B1)),1)
```

If you have 2007 or earlier you will need to use this Array formula:

```
=SMALL(IF(((Sheet2!$A$1:$A$8=A1)*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$8>=B1)),Sheet2!$B$1:$B$8),1)
```

Being an Array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter or Tab when leaving edit mode.

[image]

Column C contains the AGGREGATE() and D the Array SMALL().